# How to select all results that contain first and last name?

Tags: php, mysql

Very specific question, how can I make a select from a `$_SESSION`that contains the first, middle and last name, only the first and last name?

Example:

The output from `$_SESSION['NET']['USER']['NAME']` is `'Robert Pasha Biceps'`

What I really need on a `SELECT` is ALL that contains `'Robert Biceps'`

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=workflow_teste', 'root', '');

$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$string = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooname LIKE '".$_SESSION['NET']['USER']['NAME']."' ";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($string);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
die;
```

The `var_dump`only shows the results that have the entire name on it, but some people submit only the first and last name, and I need that results also...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the name into parts and only use first and last part in your SQL query.

```
$name = explode(' ', $_SESSION['NET']['USER']['NAME']);
$firstname = $name[0];
$lastname = $name[count($name)-1];
$string = "
    SELECT *
    FROM foo
    WHERE
        fooname LIKE '".$firstname." % ".$lastname."' OR
        fooname = '".$firstname." ".$lastname."'
";
```

From these rows:

> Robert Pasha Biceps
>   Robert Biceps
>   Robert Middlename Biceps
>   Robert Pasha
>   Pasha Biceps
>   Robert Pasha Triceps
>   Robert Other Biceps
>   Roberto Pasha Triceps

the query with the name "Robert Pasha Biceps" will select

> Robert Pasha Biceps
>   Robert Biceps
>   Robert Middlename Biceps
>   Robert Other Biceps

Also, you should look up and use prepared statements, to prevent a "[Bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) situation".

Answer (score 3):

you need to explode your session and convert it as per your requirement and pass it to query

```
$array = explode(' ', $_SESSION['NET']['USER']['NAME']);
$fooname = isset($array[0])?$array[0]:""." ". isset($array[2])?$array[2]:"";
```

and use this `$fooname` in your mysql query.Your sql will be like :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooname LIKE '%".$fooname."%' ";
```

Comment: That's how it goes! But some names have more than 2 positions, so I'll need to do a loop here to take always the first and last position, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use from % in your SQL:

```
 $string = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooname LIKE '%".$_SESSION['NET']['USER']['NAME']."%' ";
```

With this way if use type each section of name can see on result.